# How do I create a gist bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, github, repository, bookmarklet, gist

Is there a way to create a bookmarklet that adds a gist to my repo? (assuming I am logged into my Github account.)

Comment: I know I can use the commandline to push gists up as well... didn't know if anyone had more info on this. 



`curl -X POST -d '{"public":true,"files":{"addgist.txt":{"content":"This is a cool way to add a gist!"}}}' -u user:secret https://api.github.com/gists`

Answer (score 0):

You can have a bookmark that opens to `https://gist.github.com/` then you can paste / create the gist from there.